# Elegant pythonic solution for a simple loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

The function `bars` takes a list of `Foo` objects and returns a list of the `bar` attributes of those:

```
 def bars(foos):
      bars = []
      for foo in foos:
          bars.append(foo.bar)
      return bars
```

Coming from a Java background, this is the way I would have solved this in the past. But I feel that there is a more elegant pythonic way to solve this. How would I do that?

Comment: It's "pythonic" - I imagine pythonians are residents of Pythonia or something :-)

Comment: It's generally referred to as *Pythonic* - not *Pythonian* :p

Comment: @roippi I'd move to Pythonia every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[foo.bar for foo in foos]
```

(You can wrap it with `def bars(foos):`, but I think it's more readable without it)

Answer (score 1):

For your example, `@Korem`'s suggestion of a list comprehension is the ideal solution.

But here's an alternative for when you encounter that pattern where you

- initialize an empty sequence
- append to it in a loop
- return the sequence

but maybe need to do some more heavy lifting that you can't simply express in an expression (list comprehensions don't allow statements, only epxressions) - create a [generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1599111):

```
def bars(foos):
    for foo in foos:
        yield foo.bar
```

---

There's just two things to note:

- Generator functions don't return a sequence, they return a *generator*. That generator needs to be consumed by iterating over it. If you would use it like a sequence (indexing its elements for example), you'd need to turn it into a sequence e.g. by doing `list(bars(f))`:

```
>>> gen = bars(f)
>>> gen[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
>>> list(gen)[0]
42
```

- Once you iterate over it the generator will be exhausted:

```
>>> gen = bars(f)
>>> list(gen)
[42, 42, 42]
>>> list(gen)
[]
```